# Grails - ConcurrentModificationException with Oracle database

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails

I don´t know if its something with the oracle connector, hibernate or gorm., or I am missing some configuration.. but I have an appilcation that works perfectly connected to a MySQL o PostGreSQL, but when I setup an Oracle database I start to get multiple ConcurrentModificationException.

It just happens using and Oracle database (19.3, with ojdbc8.jar).

Does anyone know what I can do before start to change all my code?

Thanks!

Edit2: This appears to be the problem, but why only in Oracle?

> Caused by ConcurrentModificationException: null
> ->>  911 | checkForComodification in java.util.ArrayList$Itr

Edit: hibernate 5.1.16.

I want to reiterate that it works perfectly with other databases, and the problem appears to be at performing saves it related domain clases in cascade.

Stacktrace:

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
> at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
> at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
> at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter.doFilter(SwitchUserFilter.java:200)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
> at net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper.invoke(JspWrapper.java:152)
> at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:306)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.forward(Unknown Source)
> at grails.artefact.controller.support.RequestForwarder$Trait$Helper.forward(RequestForwarder.groovy:123)
> at grails.artefact.controller.support.RequestForwarder$Trait$Helper$forward$0.call(Unknown
> Source)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
> at com.jpicadoyasociados.seguridad.UsuarioController.forward(UsuarioController.groovy)
> at grails.artefact.controller.support.RequestForwarder$forward.callCurrent(Unknown
> Source)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
> at com.jpicadoyasociados.seguridad.UsuarioController.addImagenPrincipal(UsuarioController.groovy:612)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
> at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
> at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
> at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter.doFilter(SwitchUserFilter.java:200)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.groovy:54)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239)
> at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
> at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:54)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:155)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:64)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
> at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:911)
> at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:861)
> at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1044)
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:587)
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1295)
> at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.flushSession(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:289)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor219.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
> at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
> at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
> at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1125)
> at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:947)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:930)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethodSafe(InvokerHelper.java:92)
> at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi$_performSave_closure3.doCall(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:254)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor218.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
> at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
> at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
> at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1125)
> at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
> at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(ConvertedClosure.java:54)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:124)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.doInHibernate(Unknown Source)
> at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:299)
> at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:243)
> at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:117)
> at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.performSave(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:251)
> at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.save(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:168)
> at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:151)
> at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$save$0.call(Unknown
> Source)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
> at com.jpicadoyasociados.seguridad.UsuarioImagenPrincipal.save(UsuarioImagenPrincipal.groovy)
> at com.jpicadoyasociados.seguridad.UsuarioImagenPrincipal.save(UsuarioImagenPrincipal.groovy)
> at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$save.call(Unknown Source)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
> at com.jpicadoyasociados.seguridad.UsuarioImagenPrincipalController$__tt__create_closure6.doCall(UsuarioImagenPrincipalController.groovy:38)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
> at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
> at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
> at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1125)
> at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
> at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420)
> at com.jpicadoyasociados.seguridad.UsuarioImagenPrincipalController$__tt__create_closure6.call(UsuarioImagenPrincipalController.groovy)
> at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:436)
> at com.jpicadoyasociados.seguridad.UsuarioImagenPrincipalController$__tt__create_closure6.call(UsuarioImagenPrincipalController.groovy)
> at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
> at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
> at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
> at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:1014)
> at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:877)
> at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.withTransaction(GormEntity.groovy:939)
> at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$withTransaction$8.call(Unknown
> Source)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
> at com.jpicadoyasociados.seguridad.UsuarioImagenPrincipal.withTransaction(UsuarioImagenPrincipal.groovy)
> at com.jpicadoyasociados.seguridad.UsuarioImagenPrincipal$withTransaction.call(Unknown
> Source)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
> at com.jpicadoyasociados.seguridad.UsuarioImagenPrincipalController.$tt__create(UsuarioImagenPrincipalController.groovy:27)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
> at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
> at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
> at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1125)
> at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:947)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:930)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethodSafe(InvokerHelper.java:92)
> at com.jpicadoyasociados.seguridad.UsuarioImagenPrincipalController$_create_closure1.doCall(UsuarioImagenPrincipalController.groovy)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
> at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
> at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
> at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1125)
> at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
> at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420)
> at com.jpicadoyasociados.seguridad.UsuarioImagenPrincipalController$_create_closure1.call(UsuarioImagenPrincipalController.groovy)
> at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:436)
> at com.jpicadoyasociados.seguridad.UsuarioImagenPrincipalController$_create_closure1.call(UsuarioImagenPrincipalController.groovy)
> at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
> at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
> at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
> at com.jpicadoyasociados.seguridad.UsuarioImagenPrincipalController.create(UsuarioImagenPrincipalController.groovy)
> ... 164 common frames omitted

Comment: "Does anyone know what I can do before start to change all my code?" - Do you have a copy of a stack trace associated with the `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Comment: It is difficult to follow what is going on but it looks like a `UsuarioImagenPrincipal` is being saved.  I would look around that code for a clue.

Comment: Yeah, when that object is safe, also another one is save, the are two EntityInsertAction, but ArrayList in checkForComodification has expectedModCount = 1 and modCount = 2, so throws de ConcurrentModificationException. I can change the code, but its working with anoher databases.